# Styling breadcrumbs loaded by PHP

Tags: html, css

I'm using PHP to determine whether a second breadcrumb should be set on a page.

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php 
        $c1 = 'News';
        $c1u = "crumb1.php";
        if(isset($value))
        {
             $c2 = $value;
         $c2u ="#";
        }
?>
```

However even when $value is not set part of the CSS styling seems to be showing up like this:

[image]
How do I get rid of the rectangular bit after the first crumb?

Here's my CSS:

```
.breadcrumbs-one{
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-left:-20px;
}

.breadcrumbs-one li{
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumbs-one a{
  padding: .7em 1em .7em 2em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  //text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #212121, #ddd);   
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #212121, #ddd);
}

.breadcrumbs-one li:first-child a{
  padding-left: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumbs-one a:hover{
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumbs-one a::after,
.breadcrumbs-one a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;   
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-left: 1em solid;
  right: -1em;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;

}

.breadcrumbs-one a::after{ 
  z-index: 2;
  border-left-color: #ddd;  
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumbs-one a::before{
  border-left-color: #ccc;  
  z-index: 1; 
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumbs-one a:hover::after{
  border-left-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumbs-one .current,
.breadcrumbs-one .current:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumbs-one .current::after,
.breadcrumbs-one .current::before{
  content: normal;  
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumbs-one li:last-child a::before,
.breadcrumbs-one li:last-child a::after
{
  content: normal;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumbs-one li:nth-child(3) a::after,
.breadcrumbs-one li:nth-child(3) a::before
{
 content: normal;  
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumbs-one li:last-child a::before,
.breadcrumbs-one li:last-child a::after
{
  content: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul.breadcrumbs-one li:first-child a::after,
ul.breadcrumbs-one li:first-child a::before
{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's the PHP code I use in my header file to display the breadcrumbs:

```
<div class="container">
                <ul class="container-fluid bottomtab breadcrumbs-one">        
                <?php if(isset($c1)) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $c1u;?>"><span><?php echo $c1;?></span></a></li>
                <?php } if(isset($c2)) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $c2u;?>"><span><?php  echo $c2;?></span></a></li>   
                <?php } if(isset($c3)) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php if(isset($c3)) {echo $c3u;}?>"><span ><?php if(isset($c3)) { echo $c3;} ?></span></a></li>           
                <?php } ?> 
            </ul>
             </div>
```

Comment: write the code where PHP prints the values

Comment: have a look at my update @Ferhad

Comment: Styling is a client-side problem, so please show client-side code (the HTML that the client receives), and not server-side code (of which we can’t know the end result, because we don’t know the content of your variables etc.) Tag `php` removed, `html` added instead.

Comment: also you can try to add another test in if statement: `if(isset($value) && !empty($value))`